# Spawn thread with Swift entry point from within C function in iOS

Tags: ios, c, swift

Is it possible to spawn a thread with a Swift entry point from within a C function in iOS? For example, using gcd or the POSIX threading API (not sure if this can be used within an iOS app or not) and specifying a function signature for a Swift function?

I am not trying to solve a specific problem here, but am curious about practical limitations of Swift & C interoperability within iOS. It seems that Apple provide seamless cross-compatibility bridging Swift to C, but I haven't found much about going the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access POSIX threading mechanisms in Swift. I have some examples of working with C in [this](https://github.com/bscothern/Once) project and [this](https://github.com/bscothern/SwiftyPOSIX) other hobby project. Hopefully they are useful to you.

When working with things like `pthread_create` you will want to pass in either a Swift function or closure as the function pointer argument. I attempted going from Swift => C and having C start the thread with a Swift function via `@_cdecl` and wasn't able to get it working. It might be possible but the context of how I had things setup I couldn't get it in this case.

The other thing to keep in mind is that once you are in C land you will need a way to get back. This is typically done through `void*` as your context pointer. From Swift you will likely want to pass in an `UnsafePointer` you are managing or use `Unmanaged<T>` to directly pass a class instance you have into C and back into Swift.

Comment: Thank you @bscothern!